# Where to find WINS IP address in registry?

Tags: tcpip, wins, windows-registry

I have been writting a powershell script to remotely dump the TCPIP information from the registry of machines in my Windows Domain.  I was able to dump the default gateway, subnet mask, DHCP server and DNS server.  However, I could not find out where in the registry the WINS server IP addresses are stored.  Currently, I am targeting Windows 7 machines.

FYI.  I retrieve the TCPIP info the registry path below:
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces...

... but there is not WINS server information.

Any help will be much appreciated as I could not find it from the web so far.
Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to run "netsh interface dump"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you're looking for is here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters\Interfaces\Tcpip_{xxxxxxxxxxxx}\NameServerList

**NameServerList** is a multistring which usually has all WINS IP Addresses, it will be empty if there aren't any.

Additionally, the second part of this document covers the location of WINS / NetBios registry settings for server 2003, most of which haven't changed in Windows 7:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784026(v=ws.10).aspx